# pthread windows crash C++

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, multithreading, pthreads

I would like to create an array of length 50 with a thread, when this is done I would like to print some of the first values in every **X** seconds with a second thread. In the meanwhile the first thread can compute the next array.

The threads are functional until I try to copy some values from the computed array in some temporary variables. I have no compilation error but when I run the program I get a windows crash massage.

Without threads the **double *newarray();** function works. Returns an array which was manually allocated and filled with data.

What am I missing here?

Thread 1:

```
 double *newarray();

 void *computingU(void *)
 {
     double * U_tmp;

     while (true)

     {      
         pthread_mutex_lock( &mutexU );

         memcpy(U_tmp,newarray(),sizeof(double)*Ulenght);

         while (!Usent);   

         Usent = false;


         memcpy(Ucmd,U_tmp,sizeof(double)*Ulenght);

         pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutexU );  

         Ucomputed = true;
     }
}
```

Thread 2:

```
void *sendingCMD(void * ) {
    double * U_tmp;

    while (true)
    {

        while (!Ucomputed);

        Ucomputed = false;

        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutexU );

        memcpy(U_tmp,Ucmd,sizeof(double)*Ulenght);

        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutexU );

        Usent = true;

        for (int i = 0; i<Ulenght; i++)
        {

           printf("i= %d, u= %f", i, U_tmp[i]);

           sleep(sleepTime) ;
        }

    }
}
```

Main:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

bool Ucomputed = false, Usent = true;
double * Ucmd;
pthread_mutex_t mutexU = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
unsigned int Ulenght = 1;
int sleepTime = 1;

int main( void )
{
    #ifdef DEBUG_THREAD
    int rc1, rc2;

    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
   /* Create independent threads each of which will execute functionC */
   if( (rc1=pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &computingU, NULL)) )   {
      printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", rc1);
   }

   if( (rc2=pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &sendingCMD, NULL)) )
   {
      printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", rc2);
   }
    #endif //

    sleep(10);

    while (true);
}
```

Comment: why are you locking the mutex twice in`computingU`?

Comment: that is my mistake in cpy-ing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take the first thread in the `computingU` function, there you have a local variable:

```
double * U_tmp;
```

Later you use this variable:

```
memcpy(U_tmp,newarray(),sizeof(double)*Ulenght);
```

But nowhere do you *initialize* the variable, so it doesn't point to anything. As uninitialized (non-static) local variables have indeterminate value, so the pointer `U_tmp` will point to a seemingly random location. Writing there will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and most likely your crash.

And you have the same problem in the other thread.

Answer (score 1):

Look at:

```
 double * U_tmp;
```

You never set the pointer to anything, and then attempt to memcpy() data into it.  That will 100% crash every time.  If it doesn't your OS is broken.

Comment: There is no guarantee that it will crash. It's just likely.

Comment: It will smash the stack 100% of the time, since the total memory size of the local variables is < the memcpy command's payload.  This is also presuming the pointer happens to be the value of the start of your frame pointer, which is all but impossible. Stack smashes outside your current function's frame pointer should always result in a segfault.

Comment: No it will not "smash the stack 100% of the time". It *might* smash the stack, but it might as well write to the heap, or to an unmapped page. The thing is that there no way of knowing *where* the pointer points, its value is indeterminate.

Comment: Writing to the heap would be a segfault that should be detected by the OS.  Also, there is no heap allocation in this example to write into, which is why I said what I said.

Comment: Writing to unallocated space will not necessarily segfault. Writing to a random location on your stack will not necessarily cause problems (it may be lower on the stack than anything your program uses). You cannot rely on this causing anything untoward at all.